# Can not find how to change the size of text blocks

Tags: margins, templates

I am looking at a CV template, and I can not figure out how to make the description text blocks wider on the right.

The blocks I am talking about are the ones similar to the block starting with
"`Provided analysis of spreads..`"

What should I be looking at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template uses the `classicthesis` package, which defines the page layout by `\areaset` with specific values depending on the used fonts. You could use `\areaset` as well.

Syntax:  `\areaset[binding offset]{width}{height}`

Try for example:

```
\areaset[5mm]{360pt}{761pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5em}
```

Here I made just the text wider and shortened the marginpar width, which contains the first column.