# How to change the margins for a landscape-orientated longtable in classicthesis

Tags: margins, longtable, classicthesis

I am using the excellent `classicthesis` to typeset my thesis.  It looks great, and I would be loathe to change unless I had to, but I've run up against a problem.

I have a number of `longtable`s in the document that are in landscape orientation. I want to make the top and bottom margins, before and after the tables smaller, so that I can get more information on a page.  At the same time I want to keep the margins in the rest of the document the same.

I have:

1. Tried using the package `changepage`, but this does not seem to work with `longtable` 
   (http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-05/msg00623.html also had problems with this)
2. Considered using package `geometry` and then changing the margins before I enter the `landscape` environment with `\newgeometry`, but `classicthesis` does not appear to use `geometry` to manage page layout, so I think this will disrupt the page setup for the rest of the document
3. Tried playing with `\LTpre`, `\LTpost`, `\LTleft`, `\LTright`
4. Tried playing with the `\addmargin` command for KOMA script

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: I'm not fully certain how this might be useful yet, but [classicthesis seems to use **areaset**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7538/10103). Possibly manipulating these values are a better way to go about it. Your selected answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 6):

The interface could be better, I blame the author of the packages you are using, but this seems to work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape,longtable}
\newcounter{z}
\def\z{\stepcounter{z}[[[[[\thez]]]]]}


\makeatletter

\def\fudge#1#2{%
\addtolength\textheight{#1}%
\@colroom\textheight
\vsize\textheight
\@colht\textheight
\def\LS@rot{%
  \setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\kern-#2\rotatebox{90}{\box\@outputbox}}}}%
\clearpage}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\fudge{3cm}{1.5cm}% 3cm longer and raise by 1.5cm
\begin{longtable}{l}
\endhead
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\\z\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a whole lot of messing around ([including David's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51384/10103) which I did not seem to get to work as expected) I found it easiest to *leave the margins alone* when you just need a bit more space to fit one bigger table on a single page.

First I experimented with **areaset** since [this is what classicthesis uses to control margin sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/can-not-find-how-to-change-the-size-of-text-blocks/7538#7538). Enlarging this before *landscape* and setting it back to the original after worked. However, these margins also influence where the header is placed, which I found undesirable. This however, could still be a suitable solution to the original OP's question, although I do not immediately know how to fix the 'header issue'.

A simple negative *vspace* ended up looking the 'cleanest' for me. I removed the space allocated in classicthesis to margins (*\marginparsep + \marginparwidth*), thus resulting in similar margins to the remainder of the document.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \vspace{-\marginparsep}
    \vspace{-\marginparwidth}
    ...
    \caption{Longer table as usual still fitting on one page thanks to negative vspace.}
    \label{table:long_table}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```